# Angular Firebase - Get observable from reference field

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, observable

Let's assume I have the following firestore structure:

```
"Objects": {
  "Object1": {
    "Material_Ref": <DocRef>;
  },
  "Object2": {
    "Material_Ref": <DocRef>;
  },
}

"Materials": {
  "Name": string;
  "Type": string;
}
```

And I want to listen for changes on materials, by accessing from each object's material reference document, how could I achieve this?

```
<ul *ngIf="materials | async">
    <li *ngFor="let material of materials">
       {{ material.Name }} and {{ material.Type }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Edit: The HTML chunk above is how I want to retrieve data, and I ask what I need to do in the component to pass materials in such way. I add this, due to answers being irrelevant to what I ask for.

Answer (score 0):

i think materials should be an observable,and you have to provide an `async` pipe

```
<ul *ngIf="materials | async">
<li *ngFor="let material of materials|async">
   {{ material.Name }} and {{ material.Type }}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think I was not clear enough with my question. Html example was how I want to get materials, but I am asking about how to retrieve this observable in the component file with TS.

Comment: you have to subscribe the observables.

Comment: Yes, but how do I do that? I want to sub for each firebase document which is material ref in this case, I can maybe go ```db.collection("Objects").valueChanges()``` and do some mapping, but it is not clear for me.

Comment: when subscribing on an observables,the changes will automatically reflect back to the DOM,unless you unsubscribe the subscription;you don't want to do anything extra to reflect back the changes,